# Opening App From a Notification While Device is Locked

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification, lockscreen

Is there a way to open an app from the lock screen without putting in the password? Like the phone app can be called when a missed call notification is present. Is this possible?

I have dabbled with various ideas to make the main functionality of my app work. Through my research I cannot find an answer to my dilemma.

I want the user to be able to use the app without unlocking the phone **or** once in the app not being able to quit the app without a password essentially locking the phone from other uses except the main functionality of the app.

I know there are private frameworks that would allow it but is there a way to do it with Apple's approval?

Comment: No. This isn't possible.

Comment: I don't see a reason to perform some action without unlocking the device.

Comment: The application would allow a user to use a certain functionality without unlocking the device. Which is the very reason for the app, I am still trying to bypass this problem.

Answer (score 1):

No. This would be a security issue as you could send an APN and potentially allow someone to get into a locked device without the user's approval.

Comment: What about locking them into the app? Calling a pin page before being dismissed.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: When they go to dismiss the app by pressing the home button and the app is going into the background. Before it can be dismissed can I require a pin to be entered. Before they are allowed to go back into the rest of the phone. I hope that is clear enough. If not let me know.

Comment: And if that isn't possible. Maybe emit a loud tone whether it's on silent or not but that is the last thing I really wanted.

Comment: @BARIIIIIIICODE We aren't allowed to bypass user settings. When I put my phone on silent, I expect it to be silent. When I put a passcode, I expect my passcode to be required for entrance into my phone in any case (with the exception of the camera swipe on the lock screen and the notification center)

Comment: What about the app for TILE it can page your phone even on silent to help find your phone.